# Split vector by a field, preserving order

Tags: vector, rust

In Rust is there a simple way to split a vector like this:

```
let original_vec = vec![
    (14, "Foo", 62.3),
    (17, "Foo", 77.8),
    (25, "Bar", 33.7),
    (27, "Bar", 99.2),
    (61, "Foo", 17.4),
    (64, "Bar", 55.5),
    (77, "Bar", 31.2),
];
```

into this:

```
let res = vec![
    vec![
        (14, "Foo", 62.3),
        (17, "Foo", 77.8),
    ],
    vec![
        (25, "Bar", 33.7),
        (27, "Bar", 99.2),
    ],
    vec![
        (61, "Foo", 17.4),  // "Foo" again
    ],
    vec![
        (61, "Bar", 55.5),  // A separate group of "Bars"
        (77, "Bar", 31.2),
    ],
]
```

Just to clarify: I want to split my input vector by one of the fields in its elements. Only  *contiguous* elements with the same field value must be put in a sub-vector. The "flattened" result vector must have the same order as the original vector.

Answer (score 3):

I found exactly what I was looking for:

```
original_vec.group_by(|a, b| a.1 == b.1)
```

However, the [group_by](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.group_by) method is only available in Nightly at the moment of writing this and requires adding:

```
#![feature(slice_group_by)]
```

As an alternative, as Sebastian suggested, `group_by()` from the [itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by) crate could be used.

Comment: Or alternatively, use the [`group_by` from Itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by)

Comment: Oh, and anytime you use `#![feature]`, you need to use the Nightly version of Rust. This might confuse newcomers.

Comment: Please don't advertise nightly Rust features as the way to accomplish something in Rust (unless the question is specifically about things only supported by nightly, such as portable SIMD, advanced const generics, GATs, etc). Nightly is basically a beta-testing program for the compiler and stdlib development, and is not meant for casual usage.

Comment: @user4815162342 Good point! I am using nightly, but obviously not everyone does so. I updated my answer with clarifications.

Comment: I understand your position - if you use nightly anyway, it might make sense to prefer `group_by()` to a third-party crate. But I would argue that, even if you do use nightly, its use should not be taken as a license to use any and all unstable features. That way you create a dependency on nightly that you might not be able to get rid of, even when the feature that _originally_ led you to nightly stabilizes. Advertising nightly-only features should not be done lightly, especially when the feature is such that it can be (and is) implemented using stable Rust.

Comment: @user4815162342 I totally agree with you. I am generally reluctant to use nightly-only features, but in cases like this one, I feel more like using a nightly feature than a third party crate. Yes, there is a risk it might break at some point, but I also consider how hard it would be to fix/replace a certain implementation. Besides, if nobody were using "beta" features, they would be less-tested. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Basically I imagine the following solution

```
let original_vec = vec![
    (14, "Foo", 62.3),
    (17, "Foo", 77.8),
    (25, "Bar", 33.7),
    (27, "Bar", 99.2),
    (61, "Foo", 17.4),
    (64, "Bar", 55.5),
    (77, "Bar", 31.2),
];


type DATA = (i32, &'static str, f32);

let mut t: Vec<Vec<DATA>> = Vec::new();
let mut q: Vec<DATA> = Vec::new();
let mut p: DATA = (0, "", 0.0);

for i in original_vec
{
    if i.1 != p.1 && p.1 != "" {
        t.push(q);
        q = Vec::new();    
        q.push(i);
    }
    
    q.push(i);
    p = i;
}

println!("{:?}", t);
```